# Need Clarification in sending mail to the particular mail address in PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp

i am doing one project. In that project i want to send mail to my customers in php.
presently i am using the sendmailer.php package to sent mail.
Using this package i am sending the mail through my gmail account(i.e, SMTP Protocol).it takes 20 sec-1 min.

here my doubt is...
is it possible to send mails to customers with out using smtp protocol..

i know there is a function called mail()..
but my doubt is..!! is it send my mail to customers..?

please clarify my doubt..
i am stuck here..!!

Comment: Do you not have a mail server available on the server running your php?

Comment: ya i have the mail server available on my server.
can you please tell me how to change the smtp server settings in PHP ini file..?

Comment: Just use that server to send instead of gmail.

Comment: "how to change the smtp server settings in PHP ini file" Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, It's not possible without a SMTP.

You have to define your own SMTP server settings that normally your host provides, in the PHP ini file for example, when you use the normal mail() function.

You can change the settings like this:

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.example.com" ); 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'user@example.com');
```